# cartopy rotate winds incorrectly?

Tags: python-3.x, vector, rotation, transform, cartopy

I am trying to plot some wind vectors on maps using cartopy. However, the winds look strange so I did a simple tests using wind vectors at a ring of points at 75N. The wind vectors should points 45 degree away from both lat/lon grids because u-winds and v-winds are of the same magnitude under the stereographic projection, which should preserve the angle.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

pcproj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
lon0 = -150
mapproj = ccrs.Stereographic(
    central_longitude=lon0,central_latitude=75,
    true_scale_latitude=75,
    )
XLIM = 300e3; YLIM=300e3
dm =5; dp=1
fig = plt.figure(0,(7,7))
ax  = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.85,0.9],projection=mapproj)
      
ax.set_extent([-XLIM,XLIM,-YLIM,YLIM],crs=mapproj)
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m',color='.5',linewidth=1.5)
lon_grid = np.arange(-180,181,dm)
lat_grid = np.arange(-80,86,dp)
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True,
                  xlocs=lon_grid,ylocs=lat_grid,
                  x_inline=False,y_inline=False,
                  color='k',linestyle='dotted')

# --- draw 45 degree winds at 75N
lon = np.linspace(0,360,73)
lat = np.ones(len(lon))*75
uu  = np.ones(len(lon))*10
vv  = uu*1.
pts = mapproj.transform_points(pcproj,lon,lat)
xx = pts[...,0]; yy = pts[...,1]
ux,vx = mapproj.transform_vectors(pcproj,lon,lat,uu,vv)

ax.quiver(xx,yy,ux,vx,transform=mapproj)
```

It is clear that the wind vectors does not point 45 degrees from lat/lon grids.

[image: winds using transform_vectors from cartopy]

I check the `ux`, `vx` at 150W and 75N, the center of the projection. The wind here should be the same as in lat/lon grid but it is (3.54,13.7) rather than (10,10).
The wind vectors looks the same as using this line

```
ax.quiver(lon,lat,uu,vv,transform=pcproj)
```

This may not be a surprise because I think quiver uses `transform_vector` and `transform_points` under the hood.
I tried winds along lat/lon grid directions, they are transformed correctly.
Is this a bug in `transform_vectors` or am I using it incorrectly?

UPDATE:
As suggested by @swatchai, right now, u-wind should be divided by `cos(lat)` before being fed in to `transform_vectors`. I doubt this is the intended behavior but this normalization should be used until a future cartopy update changed the behavior. They may choose just to update the docstring. Still, something to be caution about in future cartopy updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When (lat, long) in degrees are used, a small angular distance `ds` on spherical surface has 2 components:

```
`R*dlat`  in NS direction
`R*dlon*cos(lat)`  in EW direction
```

where R is the earth radius,

the second component varies with `latitude` of the location considered,

with this in mind, the computation of `ux`, `vx` at latitude 75 degrees should be

```
rho = np.pi/180.
ux,vx = mapproj.transform_vectors(pcproj,lon,lat, uu/np.cos(75*rho), vv)
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work when u-wind is normalized with the cos(lat). The resulting vectors are the same as computed by my own function. I think this is something that should be taken care of under the hood especially when `u` and `v` are used as the vector component names. @swatchai , do you know if this is the intended behavior for cartopy or are there any plan to patch it so the users can just use the actual u-wind component? I am a little concerned my normalized code may be messed up again after a cartopy update in future.